# get HTML element outerHTML without 3rd-party libraries

Tags: java, html, parsing

At the moment, I'm using HTMLUnit and it's painfully slow (>10s).

```java
        final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url_with_hash_fragment);
        out.println(page.getElementById(hash_fragment).asXml());
```

Ideally, I'd like to do this without adding additional dependencies.  (I'm not using HTMLUnit otherwise.)

I tried using `HTMLEditorKit` but couldn't figure out how to use it for outerHTML.  I'd rather not use regular expressions, but that's preferred to waiting 10s ***and*** bloating my code.

Comment: Have you profiled to see why it's taking 10s? Is it a slow network? Or is the parsing/searching actually taking that long? How big is the page your downloading?

Comment: it's coming from localhost and the html file is 80KB